# Pro Tools 9 and 10 on the same machine

Tags: pro-tools

I need to have both Pro Tools 9 and 10 installed on the same machine.
Has anyone here this up and running? If so, how did you get it to work?
When i install PT9 it overwrites PT10. Hmmm

Gratefull for some input

Comment: Just curious what do you need both for?

Comment: I've noticed some strange behaviour in the pt10 to older version convertion. Wrong fades and eq/volume automation. I dump my tv work in different studios couple of times every week which use pt9 and i'm tired of doing things twise...

Comment: Ah that makes sense cheers. Noticed the same thing myself actually from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Within the same OS drive? I don't think so. They probably require two different sets of drivers, and having both on one machine could cause problems. You could partition your OS drive (or just install a second drive), and create two different systems...one with 9 on it, and one with 10.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine if you have two different startup drives, my iLok license works with both 9 and 10.

Comment: Thanks! Mine too, i just thought i could run them off the same drive

Answer (score 0):

............. why?

Comment: Already answered :)